# Angular CLI with Karma and PhantomJS infinite toop

Tags: angular, phantomjs, karma-runner

I am runnig an Angular CLI project and I moved from the chrome launcher to phantomjs for the karma testing. In chrome everything works fine, however in phantomjs it gets stuck in an infinite loop. 
I run the tests in singleRun.
Here is part of the output:

```
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 8 0.0.0): Executed 27 of 31 SUCCESS (0 secs / 11.2 secs)
12 05 2017 11:28:09.675:DEBUG [middleware:karma]: custom files null null
12 05 2017 11:28:09.676:DEBUG [middleware:karma]: Serving static request /context.html
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 8 0.0.0): Executed 28 of 31 SUCCESS (0 secs / 11.412 secs)
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 8 0.0.0): Executed 58 of 31 SUCCESS (0 secs / 22.526 secs)
12 05 2017 11:28:21.685:DEBUG [middleware:karma]: custom files null null
12 05 2017 11:28:21.685:DEBUG [middleware:karma]: Serving static request /context.html
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 8 0.0.0): Executed 59 of 31 SUCCESS (0 secs / 22.747 secs)
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 8 0.0.0): Executed 76 of 31 SUCCESS (0 secs / 28.024 secs)
```

And it goes on and on and on like this until I stop it.
Here is my karma.conf.js.

```
// Karma configuration file, see link for more information
// https://karma-runner.github.io/0.13/config/configuration-file.html

module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular/cli'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-phantomjs-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
      require('@angular/cli/plugins/karma')
    ],
    client: {
      clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    files: [
      { pattern: './src/test.ts', watched: false }
    ],
    preprocessors: {
      './src/test.ts': ['@angular/cli']
    },
    mime: {
      'text/x-typescript': ['ts', 'tsx']
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      reports: ['html', 'lcovonly'],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
    },
    angularCli: {
      environment: 'dev'
    },
    reporters: config.angularCli && config.angularCli.codeCoverage
      ? ['progress', 'coverage-istanbul']
      : ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_DEBUG,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['PhantomJS_custom'],
    customLaunchers: {
      'PhantomJS_custom': {
        base: 'PhantomJS',
        flags: ['--load-images=false'],
        debug: false
      }
    },
    phantomjsLauncher: {
      // Have phantomjs exit if a ResourceError is encountered (useful if karma exits without killing phantom) 
      exitOnResourceError: false
    },
    singleRun: false
  });
};
```

Any help would be very appreciated!
Thanks!